# Cannot unpack non-iterable SerializerMethodField object in Django DRF

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to assign the list from `SerializerMethodField()` `return` to a set of two fields, as:

```py
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    postvotes, postvote = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    
    def get_postvotes(self, obj):
        qset = PostVote.objects.filter(Q(post=obj))
        votes = [PostVoteSerializer(m).data for m in qset]
        vote = sum(vote['vote'] for vote in votes)
        return [votes, vote] # votes[], vote: Integer
```

However, this fails with the title-metioned error.

How can I solve this? Thanks.

Comment: I posted a solution to your immediate error, but I doubt that it will actually work the way you want. What do you want the serialized JSON or XML to look like for this field?

Comment: Hi, thanks, I'm reading it. From the above code I wanted to get e.g. `{id: 1, postvotes: [], postvote: 0}`; So basically I want to make sure to split the two properties, not like `{id: 1, postvotes: [[], 0]}`

Comment: Also, I don't want to call `SerializerMethodField()
` simply two times just for `vote`, because the `votes = ..` line loads a little. that's why I'm trying to define the set of properties in a single SerializerMethodField()

Comment: `SerializerMethodField()` will serialize a single attribute in the JSON. It won't create two separate attributes like you want.

Comment: okay, I understand. I'll go with returning list or object as a workaround. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error happens because `SerializerMethodField` isn't an iterable. You are not calling `get_postvotes()` directly to get the list which it returns.

To fix the current problem, just declare the field as normal:

```
postvotes = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
```

Then when you access the value of the `postvotes` field in the usual way, you will get the list of two items:

```
votes, vote = obj.postvotes
```

This change will fix the immediate error, but I'm unsure if it will work the way you intend. So here are some alternative solutions:

1. Use a composite field instead, such as `ListField` or `DictField`
2. Create a custom field by extending `serializers.Field`. See [the docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#custom-fields) for details.

Another possibility is to declare two `SerializerMethodField`s:

```
votes = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
vote_count = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
```

Since these are attached to methods in your serializer class, you can do whatever you want. For example, you could have a helper method to count the votes:

```
    def count_votes(self, obj):
        qset = PostVote.objects.filter(Q(post=obj))
        self._votes = [PostVoteSerializer(m).data for m in qset]
        self._vote_count = sum(vote['vote'] for vote in votes)
```

Then you can just call the method from the appropriate methods:

```
    def get_votes(self, obj):
        if self._votes is None:
            self.count_votes()
        return self._votes
```

Similarly for `get_vote_count()`. And be sure to initialize member variables:

```
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.super(*args, **kwargs)
        self._votes = None
        self._vote_count = None
```